# java.sql.SQLException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic

When I was tried to access data from database using application server e.g **weblogic** or **jdbc** type3 driver for it I had created **JNDI** '**orc**' in **weblogin** and same JNDI '**orc**' define java file.But when I had executed this code then **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException** occurred.
If any one have answer of this problem. Please help me.

I really sorry for my grammatical and formatting mistake because i was not aware.

Thank you
Banti kumar

```
    import java.sql.Driver;
    import java.sql.Connection; 
    import java.sql.Statement; 
    import java.sql.ResultSet; 
    import java.util.Properties; 
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class NetworkProtocalDriver{ 
       public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
          String url = null;
          Driver driver = null;
          Properties props = new Properties();
      try{
           driver = (Driver)Class.forName("weblogic.jdbc.rmi.Driver").newInstance();
           url = "jdbc:weblogic:rmi";


           props.put("weblogic.server.url","t3://localhost:7001");
           props.put("weblogic.jdbc.datasource","orc");
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
         System.out.println("Sorry driver class is not available ? ? ?");
      }
      catch(InstantiationException e){
       System.out.println("Sorry an instance of Driver class is not created ? ? ? ?");
      }
      try{
           Connection con = driver.connect(url,props);
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");      
           if(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2));

           con.close();
           stmt.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is not a question. Please edit your post and post the stacktrace also. EDIT : Who upvoted this and why?

Comment: it seems to me that your datasource in WebLogic console is not targeted to the server where you are deploying the application and when it is the time to find the object with jndi name "orc" server is throwing this exception. But you should be really more specific with your questions..

Comment: Sir,web logic server could not found to specified jndi name "orc" while jndi name is correct.

Comment: @BantiKumar Please don't deface you post by rolling back our improvements. Instead, edit your question and add additional information about your problem.